# How to flatten json file in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have json file structure as shown below.evry time json file structure will change in pyspark how we handle flatten any kind of json file. Can u help me on this.

```
root 
|-- student: struct (nullable = true) 
|-- children: struct (nullable = true) 
|-- parent: struct (nullable = true 
| |-- id: string (nullable = true) 
| |-- type: string (nullable = true) 
| |-- date: string (nullable = true) 
|-- multipliers: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: double (containsNull = true) 
|-- spawn_time: string (nullable = true) 
|-- type: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: root
 |-- student: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- children: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- parent: struct (nullable = true
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- multipliers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- spawn_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

Comment: Please write the code in your question rather than as a comment. Also please provide the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a recursive function to determine the columns to select, by building a flat list of fully-named prefixes in the `prefix` accumulator parameter.

Note that it will work on any format that supports nesting, not just JSON (Parquet, Avro, etc).

Furthermore, the input can have any schema, but this example uses:

```json
{"c1": {"c3": 4, "c4": 12}, "c2": "w1"}
{"c1": {"c3": 5, "c4": 34}, "c2": "w2"}
```

The original `df` shows as:

```
+-------+---+
|     c1| c2|
+-------+---+
|[4, 12]| w1|
|[5, 34]| w2|
+-------+---+
```

The code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


# return a list of all (possibly nested) fields to select, within a given schema
def flatten(schema, prefix: str = ""):
    # return a list of sub-items to select, within a given field
    def field_items(field):
        name = f'{prefix}.{field.name}' if prefix else field.name
        if type(field.dataType) == StructType:
            return flatten(field.dataType, name)
        else:
            return [col(name)]
    return [item for field in schema.fields for item in field_items(field)]


df = spark.read.json(path)

print('===== df =====')
df.printSchema()

flattened = flatten(df.schema)
print('flattened =', flatten(df.schema))
print('===== df2 =====')
df2 = df.select(*flattened)
df2.printSchema()

df2.show()
```

As you will see in the output, the `flatten` function returns a flat list of columns, each one fully named (using "parent_col.child_col" naming format).

Output:

```
===== df =====
root
 |-- c1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)

flattened = [Column<b'c1.c3'>, Column<b'c1.c4'>, Column<b'c2'>]
===== df2 =====
root
 |-- c3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+---+
| c3| c4| c2|
+---+---+---+
|  4| 12| w1|
|  5| 34| w2|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I am getting syntax errors for udf... Can explain me detail.

Comment: def flatten(schema, prefix: str = ""):   --in this line syntax error at first :

Comment: And also I don't want specify any column names it should pick automatically from input data frame

Comment: This approach doesn't specify column names. If you're using an old version of Python, please remove the type annotations and try again: `def flatten(schema, prefix = ""):`

Comment: hi @ELinda, thanks for the code. it works great. If the json goes deeper in level, as in struct inside array, how can I update this code to work? for eg. [{}, {}]

Comment: This is sooo beautiful!!!